# Как вывести в консоль объект из DevTools (Network)?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой вот объект в Network, хотелось бы как-то работать с ним через консоль, но возникли сложности с его получением. Как можно получать подобные объекты и помещать их в переменные?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/ra3hYvT.png]

Comment: Preview - это ответ сервера. В чём проблема взять Response оного? Там он в "сыром" виде

Comment: сервис писал не я, по этому посторонние запросы скорее всего защищены. но возможно как-то можно из браузера получить эту информацию, раз он её так выводит?

Comment: я уже написал как....вкладка Response  вместо Preview

Comment: вкладка response просто позволяет мне копировать этот объект, но мне нужно именно взаимодействовать с ним программно через консоль, чтобы не копировать мышкой и вставлять, а именно обращаться к объекту напрямую каким-то образом

Comment: Ничего не ясно.....